# Virtualbox VM loses IP randomly after some time

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

This happens about every 30 - 90 minutes I guess, not exactly sure.

I have a Linux Mint VM with a secondary Host-Only adapter (the first one is the standard NAT).

`ifconfig` of the interface when working:

```
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9b:62:20  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2838:d4ae:d350:b822/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1586768 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:10166856 (10.1 MB)
```

and when not working:

```
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9b:62:20  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6441 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1574095 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:10162092 (10.1 MB)
```

If I bring the interface down and then up again it will work again, but it's a nuisance and I have to restart the web server as well.

How do I stop it from losing the IP?

Which log files would hold any useful info on this issue?

**EDIT:** Could it be a power management issue?

**EDIT 2:** Sometimes it only loses the IPv4:

```
enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9b:62:20  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2838:d4ae:d350:b822/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15434 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38413 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3296715 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:65539683 (65.5 MB)
```

Comment: can you use a static ip?

Comment: @Blaine it seems to work with a static IP, but for some reason I lose internet access if I do that.  If I bring down the host-only one, then the NAT seems to work again...

Comment: Seems to be fixed when I check "use this connection only for resources on its network" under "Routes" for the host-only.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Blaine's suggestion, I set up a static ip for the VM, using this link:

http://coding4streetcred.com/blog/post/VirtualBox-Configuring-Static-IPs-for-VMs

The only issue after that was that I had to check "use this connection only for resources on its network" under "Routes" for the host-only, so that the internet traffic would be routed through the NAT and not the host-only.